# How can I get automatically primaryKey name of any table in yii framework

Tags: php, yii

How can I get automatically primaryKey name of any table in yii framework.I want to use primary key automatically  in `framework\gii\generators\model\templates\default\model.php` .
primaryKey is XXX

```
return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
    'criteria'=>$criteria,
     'sort'=>array(
     'defaultOrder'=>' XXX DESC',
    ),
));
```

Answer (score 0):

For gii you can use:

```
$this->tableSchema->primaryKey;
```

Or generally depending on the situation:

```
$user = new User;
$user->tableSchema->primaryKey;
```

Answer (score 0):

look at this doc http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbTableSchema

```
$model->tableSchema->primaryKey;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend using default scope instead of default order in CActiveDataProvider. Main reason is that default scope allows to sort record even when used in relation.
Default scope:

```
 public function defaultScope() {
        return array(
            'order' => $this->getTableAlias(false, false).'.'.$this->tableSchema->primaryKey.' DESC'
        );
    }
```

I also used in this example getTableAlias as it prevents column name collision. 
So you are left with much simplier data provider:

```
return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
    'criteria'=>$criteria,
));
```